# How to stop spring security from taking my application context to login.jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot, spring security spring mvc application.

but whenever I try to access http://localhost:8080/MyApp, it redirects me to login page which I don't want.

What I want is to have a guest access to my application in which some of  the urls should be authentication free and My Home page loads when I access http://localhost:8080/MyApp. I want it to be accessed by everyone. There are some features which will accessed only after login, I want only those api endpoints to be authenticated.

My Code for the security configuration class is :-

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/MyApp").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/MyApp/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/products").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .csrf();
    }



    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your configuration class for spring security in the method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

}
```

try to add **`.antMatchers("/MyApp").permitAll()`**

or just **`.antMatchers("/").permitAll()`**

Comment: No luck. Still same issue. :-(

Comment: your app running on the context /MyApp ? And is index.jsp present in your application or you are using request mapping with url "/" in your controller to return home page?

Comment: request mapping with url "/".. corresponding to this mapping i've home.jsp

Comment: application base url set to use /MyApp ?

Comment: yes in application.properties i've set server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp

Comment: ok, spring security filter? may not be there as it is spring boot

Comment: I am using Spring boot , I don't have any filter config file or webappinitializer.. Sorry If I did not get you..

Comment: .antMatchers("/").permitAll() should have done the things as required

Answer (score -2):

You must configure your security. To do it you must create a Bean that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. You must configure the options as you need and add the url pattern that you want to make accessible to the public (demilitarized).

An example:

```
@Configuration
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()                
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and() // Login Form configuration for all others
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and() //Logout Form configuration
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Although this configuration will depend on how you render your html, maybe you need additional configuration if you use other frameworks like Freemaker.

Comment: Hi Jose, I have updated my code , I still can't access http://localhost:8080/MyApp (which indirectly points to home.jsp). After spring security it always loads me to login.jsp. However if I change my controller and make http://localhost:8181/MyApp/home connected to home.jsp then it works. how can i make context path of the app not ask for login